# Using PHP, how do I search an array for a partial string and then display multiple sections of the array?

Tags: php, arrays, search, multidimensional-array, substring

I have discovered that I don't think I want to search for array keys and print their value, I wish to search for a part filled  entry, i.e, If I searched 'haw' it would return each row with Hawthorn, Hawt etc in the first column.

This is what I'm using for the search currently, and it works fine if I give full names for the values (although I realise its probably ugly and inefficient). However, I would like to be able to search for 'geoff' and find all the geoffrey's, then display the relevant sections of their row.

I have tried various methods of converting strings to arrays and arrays to strings based around errors I get from the various functions I'm trying, but I just can't resolve it. It's such a common feature in searches I really think I'm missing something important. I'm so new, I need help!

Most recently I attempted to use 'In_array' but that didn't help either. Thanks if anyone can sort it!

> 

```
    $sitename = $_GET['sitename'];
    $upsitename = strtolower($sitename);

    $area = $_GET['area'];
    $uparea = strtolower($area);

    $postcode = $_GET['postcode'];
    $uppostcode = strtolower($postcode);

    $file = fopen("houselist.csv","r");
    ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings',TRUE);

    while ( ! feof ( $file ) ) {
        $show = fgetcsv($file);

    if(($upretailer != NULL)and( $upsitename == NULL)and($uparea == NULL)) {        
            if($show[0] == $upretailer) {
                echo "<table class='output'>
    <tr><td>$show[0] </td><td>$show[1]</td><td>$show[2]</td><td>$show[5]</td><td>$show[6]</td><td>$show[8]</td>
                            </table>";
                    }
                }

        if(($upretailer != NULL) and ($upsitename != NULL)and($uparea == NULL)) {
            if(($show[0] == $upretailer) and ($show[2] == $upsitename)) {
                echo "<table class='output'>
                                <tr><td>$show[0] </td><td>$show[1]</td><td>$show[2]</td><td>$show[5]</td><td>$show[6]</td><td>$show[8]</td>
                            </table>";
                                }
                            }

        if(($upretailer != NULL) and ($upsitename != NULL)and($uparea != NULL)) {
            if(($show[0] == $upretailer) and ($show[2] == $upsitename) and ($show[5] == $uparea)) {
                echo "<table class='output'>
                                <tr><td>$show[0] </td><td>$show[1]</td><td>$show[2]</td><td>$show[5]</td><td>$show[6]</td><td>$show[8]</td>
                            </table>";
                                }
                            }

        if(($upretailer == NULL) and ($upsitename != NULL)and($uparea != NULL)) {
            if(($show[2] == $upsitename) and ($show[5] == $uparea)) {
                echo "<table class='output'>
                                <tr><td>$show[0] </td><td>$show[1]</td><td>$show[2]</td><td>$show[5]</td><td>$show[6]</td><td>$show[8]</td>
                            </table>";
                                }
                            }

        if(($upretailer == NULL) and ($upsitename == NULL)and($uparea != NULL)) {
            if($show[5] == $uparea) {
                echo "<table class='output'>
                                <tr><td>$show[0] </td><td>$show[1]</td><td>$show[2]</td><td>$show[5]</td><td>$show[6]</td><td>$show[8]</td>
                            </table>";
                                }
                            }

        if(($upretailer == NULL) and ($upsitename != NULL)and($uparea == NULL)) {
            if($show[2] == $upsitename) {
                echo "<table class='output'>
                                <tr><td>$show[0] </td><td>$show[1]</td><td>$show[2]</td><td>$show[5]</td><td>$show[6]</td><td>$show[8]</td>
                            </table>";
                                }
                            }
        if(($upretailer != NULL) and ($upsitename == NULL)and($uparea != NULL)) {
            if(($show[0] == $u)and($show[5] == $uparea)){
                echo "<table class='output'>
                                <tr><td>$show[0] </td><td>$show[1]</td><td>$show[2]</td><td>$show[5]</td><td>$show[6]</td><td>$show[8]</td>
                            </table>";
                                }
                            }
    }
        fclose($file);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Define search/compare function somewhere at the begining of your script

```
function searchString($haystack, $needle) {
    return strpos($haystack, $needle) === 0 ? true : false;
}
```

and use it in IF statements f.e.

```
if(searchString($show[0], $upretailer) && searchString($show[2], $upsitename)) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks for the help, I'll get on it today.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$sitename = $_GET['sitename'];
$upsitename = strtolower($sitename);

$area = $_GET['area'];
$uparea = strtolower($area);

$postcode = $_GET['postcode'];
$uppostcode = strtolower($postcode);

$file = fopen("houselist.csv","r");
ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings',TRUE);

$i=0;

while ( ! feof ( $file ) ) {
$show = fgetcsv($file);

  $track="nope";

  foreach ($show as $val) {

   if (strpos($val,$upsitename) !== false)
   {
    $track="true";
    echo $upsitename . " appeared in " . $val . " on line " . $i . "</br>";
   }
   if (strpos($val,$uppostcode) !== false)
   {
    $track="true";
    echo $uppostcode . " appeared in " . $val . " on line " . $i . "</br>";
   }
   if (strpos($val,$uparea) !== false) 
   {
    $track="true";
    echo $uparea . " appeared in " . $val . " on line " . $i . "</br>";
   }

  }

  if($track=="true")
  {
  echo 
  "</br></br><table class='output'>
  <tr>
  <td>$show[0] </td>
  <td>$show[1]</td>
  <td>$show[2]</td>
  <td>$show[5]</td>
  <td>$show[6]</td>
  <td>$show[8]</td>
  </tr>
  </table>";
  }

$i++;      
}

fclose($file);
?>
```

Comment: Also thanks, I'll give a go of both of these later. Many thanks peeps!